# Call an overloaded << operator on a derived class in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

Assuming you've implemented the << operator correctly, how can you properly call it on a vector of derived classes?

Say you've got class Base, and from it DerivedOne, DerivedTwo, etc.  Then in your main you have a vector of pointers to various derived type objects. Something along the lines of:

```
void showItems(vector<Base*>  items) {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        cout << items[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: You can't do this directly; `<<` only invokes `operator<<(std::ostream &, const Base &)`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Actually, it invokes `operator<<( std::ostream& Base const* )`.  Which most likely only invokes a type conversion, and outputs a `void*`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Ah, yeah, I assumed the OP had dereferenced further.

Answer (score 7):

Implement something like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual ostream& print(ostream&) const = 0;
};

ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Base& base)
{
  return base.print(out);
}
```